# Basis vectors as a differentiation of position vector

Tags: vector-spaces, tensors

Basis vectors are defined as $\vec {E_i}=\vec{E_i}(x_1,x_2,x_3)=\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial x^i}$ i=1,2,3.
In spherical coordinate system $x^1=r, x^2=\theta, x^3=\phi$

position vector $\vec {R}=r \hat{r}$.

That means $\hat {r}=\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial r}=\hat {r}$

But $\hat {\theta}=\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial \theta}=r\hat {\theta}$

Similarly $\hat {\phi}=\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial \phi}=r\hat {\phi}$

Where am I wrong? Why is r  appearing?

Comment: $\hat{r} = \sin (\theta) \cos (\phi) \hat{x} + \sin (\theta) \sin(\phi) \hat{y} + \cos (\theta) \hat{z}$

Comment: Differentiating this gives what we need. But we are differentiating position vector and it doesn't give the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the scale factors

$$
\hat{e}_\alpha = \frac{1}{h^\alpha}\frac{\partial {\bf x}}{\partial u^\alpha}
$$

As an example

$$
{\bf x} =  \pmatrix{r\sin\theta\cos\phi \\ r\sin\theta\sin\phi \\ r \cos\theta}
$$

So

$$
\frac{\partial {\bf x}}{\partial \theta} =  \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\pmatrix{r\sin\theta\cos\phi \\ r\sin\theta\sin\phi \\ r \cos\theta} = \pmatrix{r\cos\theta\sin\phi \\ r\cos\theta\cos\phi \\ -r\sin\theta}
$$

The scale factor is just

$$
h^2 = [r^2\cos^2\theta(\sin^2\phi + \cos^2\phi) + r^2\sin^2\theta]^{1/2} = r
$$

So the unit vector is

$$
\hat{e}_2 = \pmatrix{\cos\theta\sin\phi \\ \cos\theta\cos\phi \\ -\sin\theta}
$$

Comment: But what about the way of defining basis vectors? As mentioned above it doesn't mention scale factors.

Comment: @AsitSrivastava The vectors are defined through the derivatives as you said, but they are not unitary. You need to scale them first, hence the scale factors

Answer (score 0):

In Cartesian co-ordinates the unit vectors parallel to the co-ordinate axes $\hat{x}, \hat{y}, \hat{z}$ do not change with position. So if we have $\vec{R}=x\hat{x}+y\hat{y}+z\hat{z}$ then we are used to seeing

$\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial x}=\hat{x}$ etc.

However, in other co-ordinate systems this is not true. In particular, in spherical co-ordinates the direction of the $\hat{r}$ vector changes depending on $\theta$ and $\phi$ - so we should more properly write $\hat{r}$ as $\hat{r}(\theta, \phi)$. So

$\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial \theta}=r\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial \theta}=r \hat{\theta}$

$\Rightarrow \hat{\theta} =\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial \theta}$

and similarly for $\phi$:

$\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial \phi}=r\frac{\partial\vec{r}}{\partial \phi}=r\sin \theta \hat{\phi}$

$\Rightarrow \hat{\phi} =\frac{1}{r \sin \theta}\frac{\partial\vec{R}}{\partial \phi}$